# How to write regex for bullet space digit and dot

Tags: java, regex

I am using regex for my sentence contains bullet space digit and dot.

```
• 1. This is sample Application
• 2. This is Sample java program
```

regex:

```
•\\s\\d\\.\\s[A-z]

Required output:
This is sample Application.
This is Sample java program.
```

its not working.Please Suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Try replacing the bullet with it's code point (in form of `\\uxxxx`)

Comment: What should be the expected output?

Comment: removing bullet space digit and dot and space from the sentence My expected out put is This is sample Application.                           This is Sample java program.

Answer (score 15):

To match the bullet character you will need to use the unicode escape sequence.  However Unicode defines several bullet styles, so it's probably best to allow for all of them:

```
[\u2022,\u2023,\u25E6,\u2043,\u2219]\s\d\.\s[A-z]
```

This should match the following bullet styles:

- Bullet (•)
- Triangular Bullet (‣)
- White Bullet (◦)
- Hyphen Bullet (⁃)
- Bullet Operator (∙)

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%80%A2

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the actual 'bullet,' use the unicode equivalent:

```
\u2022\s\d\.\s[A-z]
```

For more info see [Unicode Character 'BULLET' (U+2022)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) and [Regex Tutorial - Unicode Characters and Properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

**EDIT:**
To split the lines (assuming each line is a separate string) try this out:

```
String firstString = "• 1. This is sample Application";
System.out.println(firstString.split("\\u2022\\s\\d\\.\\s")[1]);
```

This works because `String.split` cuts your string into an array wherever there's a match. The `[1]` addresses the second item in that array, being the second half of the split.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
String a="• 1. This is sample Application";
a = a.replaceAll("\\u2022(?=\\s\\d\\.\\s[A-z])",""); // this will remove the • if only the bulet have \\s\\d\\.\\s[A-z] patern after it.
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why `regex`? you can use this way

```
   String str="• 1. This is sample Application";
   String newStr=str.replaceAll("\\•|\\.",""); 
   // Or str.replaceAll("\\u2022|\\.","");u2022 is unicode value of bullet 
   System.out.println(newStr);
```