# NewtonSoft Json parser error: bullet characters in JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON file which has some text with bullet characters "•". When I try to parse it with Newtonsoft Json, it throws error that the parsing is failing with an error "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered". How do we replace all the bullet characters from the string please?

```
string strFileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(JsonFilePath).Replace("\0", string.Empty); 
JObject reportLayout = JObject.Parse(strFileContent);
```

This is JSON the part in the file that is causing the issue. I tried string replace "•\t" but it is not working either.

```
"paragraphs":[
    {"textRuns":[
        {
            "value":"•\tItem1"}]            
    }
    ,{"textRuns":[
        {
            "value":"•\tItem2"}]            
     }
    ,{"textRuns":[
        {
            "value":"•\tItem3"}]        
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you put your json file data?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the json section that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove bullets from your file, you need to replace the bullets using Regex.Replace with an input pattern having unicodes for bullets like below

```
string strFileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(JsonFilePath);
string finalString = Regex.Replace(strFileContent, "[\\u2022,\\u2023,\\u25E6,\\u2043,\\u2219]\\s\\d", " ");
```

You can then use the finalString in parsing your JSON

Note that in the above patterns, u2022 is for (.) bullet.

This should match the following bullet styles:

1. Bullet (•)
2. Triangular Bullet (‣)
3. White Bullet (◦)
4. Hyphen Bullet (⁃)
5. Bullet Operator (∙)

Had some help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266529/how-to-write-regex-for-bullet-space-digit-and-dot/18266778/#answers-header)

Comment: Thanks. I used the regex but still get the same error. I have edited my question to include  the json section that causes the issue.